# SQL - SELECT - FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, select, left-join

```
VISITSEXIT              VISITSENTRY               VISITOR
idvisitsexit            idvisitsentry             idvisitor 
idvisitsentry           idvisitante               visitor 
idvisitor               visitor
visitor
dateexit
timeexit
```

I need to select the table VISITSEXIT where when she bring the VISITSENTRY also will bring idvisitor and description of idvisitor (visitor).

Comment: What query have you written so far and why doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple straightforward [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) will give you what you want:

```
SELECT
  t.idvisitor,
  t.visitor,
  t.dateexit,
  t.timeext,
  ... -- the rest of the columns you want to select 
FROM VISITSEXIT       AS t
INNER JOIN VisitEntry AS e ON t.idvisitentry = e.visitentry
INNER JOIN Visitor    AS v ON e.idvisitante  = v.idvisitor;
```

You might also need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to include those unmatched rows from the other tables. See this post for more information about the `JOIN` types:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)